# JNA allocate buffer FIXED_INFO throws Invalid memory access

Tags: java, jna

I have a simple call to new FIXED_INFO(buffer) that is resulting in java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access.  I can't for the life of me figure out why this is failing:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.IPHlpAPI;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.IPHlpAPI.FIXED_INFO;

public void fixedInfoTest() {
  int bufferSize = 648;
  Memory buffer = new Memory(bufferSize);
  FIXED_INFO fixedInfo = new FIXED_INFO(buffer);
}
```

The exception is thrown on the "new FIXED_INFO(buffer)" call.

```
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native._getPointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.getPointer(Native.java:2211)
    at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getPointer(Pointer.java:642)
    at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getValue(Pointer.java:367)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.readField(Structure.java:732)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.read(Structure.java:591)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.autoRead(Structure.java:2141)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.conditionalAutoRead(Structure.java:561)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.updateStructureByReference(Structure.java:690)
    at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getValue(Pointer.java:367)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.readField(Structure.java:732)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.read(Structure.java:591)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.IPHlpAPI$FIXED_INFO.<init>(IPHlpAPI.java:208)
    at com.magnicomp.test.unit.WindowsNativeTest.fixedInfoTest(WindowsNativeTest.java:43)
```

The above test does work sometimes but fails frequently.  Test systems are Win 10, Win Server 2016.  JNA version 5.4.0

In my production code the fixedInfo is used for:

```
IntByReference bufferSize = new IntByReference();
int result = IPHlpAPI.INSTANCE.GetNetworkParams(Pointer.NULL, bufferSize);
Validate.isTrue(result == WinNT.ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW, 
                "GetNetworkParams buffer size failed: " + Win32Error.getErrorMessage(result));      

Memory buffer = new Memory(bufferSize.getValue());
FIXED_INFO fixedInfo = new FIXED_INFO(buffer);

result = IPHlpAPI.INSTANCE.GetNetworkParams(fixedInfo.getPointer(), bufferSize);
if (result != WinNT.ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    log.error("GetNetworkParams failed: %s", Win32Error.getErrorMessage(result));
    return;
}
String domain = new String(fixedInfo.DomainName).trim(); 

log.info("GetNetworkParams gave domain=\"%s\"", domain);
```

Here are some examples I've found:

https://www.javatips.net/api/oshi-master/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/software/os/windows/WindowsNetworkParams.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  This code works:

```
IntByReference bufferSize = new IntByReference();
int result = IPHlpAPI.INSTANCE.GetNetworkParams(Pointer.NULL, bufferSize);
Validate.isTrue(result == WinNT.ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW, 
        "GetNetworkParams buffer size failed: " + Win32Error.getErrorMessage(result));
log.info("BufferSize=%d", bufferSize.getValue());

Memory buffer = new Memory(bufferSize.getValue());

// Now retrieve the actual FIXED_INFO
result = IPHlpAPI.INSTANCE.GetNetworkParams(buffer, bufferSize);
if (result != WinNT.ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    log.error("GetNetworkParams failed: %s", Win32Error.getErrorMessage(result));
    return;
}
FIXED_INFO fixedInfo = new FIXED_INFO(buffer);

String domain = new String(fixedInfo.DomainName).trim(); 

log.info("GetNetworkParams gave domain=\"%s\"", domain);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're providing a `Memory` instance to the constructor of `FIXED_INFO` - that constructor is meant for memory that contains proper data in the structure, and you're just passing empty uninitialized memory. The constructor of `FIXED_INFO` will try to read the structure and pointers in it, and find that the data in the structure is invalid.

What you should do is to call the constructor of `FIXED_INFO` that doesn't take any arguments. This constructor will allocate the right amount of memory and initialize it properly for you.

Change your code to:

```
// Memory buffer = new Memory(bufferSize); -- remove this line
FIXED_INFO fixedInfo = new FIXED_INFO();
```

Source of this information: looking through the source code for JNA and the library that contains FIXED_INFO.

- JNA [`Structure`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/Structure.java) class (from your stacktrace)
- [`FIXED_INFO`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/IPHlpAPI.java)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that but if I change my code as suggested than the GetNetworkParams() returns empty (zero length) values for fixedInfo attributes liked FIXED_INFO.DomainName.  Also I found several examples via google search and all use the FIXED_INFO(new Memory(size)) approach.

Comment: But do these examples work? Do you have links to them?

Comment: I can only find one example right now.  Added it to the end of my post.

Comment: As the author of the example, I'll note that @ErwinBolwidt is correct and that's an older/uglier version of the code. The correct sequence is to pass an empty buffer to the `GetNetworkParams()` function, which gets populated with data.  Then you "cast" to `FIXED_INFO` using the `new FIXED_INFO(buffer)` call.  Key point here is that `buffer` has the correct data in it before the call.  Your code as posted should work if you move the `FIXED_INFO fixedInfo = new FIXED_INFO(buffer);` line down below the method call, and call the method with the `buffer`.

Comment: Also to clarify, the code may have worked originally in the project you cite but the `FIXED_INFO` structure that I contributed to JNA may not have had the same bells and whistles so the code example is based on a different structure (`oshi.jna.platform.windows.IPHlpAPI.FIXED_INFO;`) than the current JNA version of `FIXED_INFO`.  Working code based on the JNA version is [here](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/fea60491ed77b247e5c76c0f85b8b7d33ade7ac2/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/software/os/windows/WindowsNetworkParams.java#L69)

Comment: More insight into why you're getting the error you're getting using my "old" code in [this JNA Mailing List thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jna-users/FIXED_INFO%7Csort:date/jna-users/UD3UkxZW0vE/c7kFhLW8BAAJ), when I discovered why the memory error is intermittent.